# Cannot populate input field without having to inspect input field element first?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, input, getelementbyid

I am attempting to populate a form's "First Name" field by using

`document.getElementById('u_4SM_4607').value = 'Peet';`

in the console of my Google Chrome browser.

I get this error when I run the command to fill in the "First Name" field:

```js
VM183:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null
    at <anonymous>:1:45
```

However, if I inspect the "First Name" field, and then run `document.getElementById('u_4SM_4607').value = 'Peet';`, it works and will populate the "First Name" field with "Peet".

Why do I get that error code, and why does it only work when I inspect the field first?

Here is the `input` element of the "First Name" field:

```html
<input name="u_4SM_4607" id="u_4SM_4607" type="text" value="" class=" u-full-width" placeholder="Your first name" aria-required="true">
```

Here is the URL of the web form I am attempting to practice on:

https://formsmarts.com/html-form-example

Answer (score 0):

I think its bacause the form is embeded from an external source with iframe.
its like a nother web-page. so if you dont refer to this web-page it does not work.